# Do I need to be familiar with the PS3 controller to succeed in Demons Souls?

Tags: ps3, demons-souls

I am intrigued by the Multiplayer offered by Demon Souls, and after hearing so much about it I am quite keen to give it a try. The problem is I have not touched a PS3 controller before (and it has been a while since my SNES :))

The game is hard, I know that, but I want to know if the controls add to the difficulty. Do I require some experience with a PS3 controller before starting Demons Souls?

Comment: The PS3 controller has a button layout almost identical to the SNES, with the addiiton of a second L and R button and two analog sticks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I bought my PS3 a few months ago, and the first game I bought was Demon's Souls, and I had no problem with the controls. I also never owned a PlayStation console before (although my sister had a PS2, for which I played through a couple games).

As such, no. The controls shouldn't add any additional difficulty to the game - and if you did find some due to the controls, they shouldn't last anymore more then 30 minutes, by which point you'll know the controller well.

Comment: I would say though that Demon's Souls is brutally DIFFICULT - so if the difficulty itself is a problem for you, you might very well have trouble picking up the controls because you're busy panicking all the time.

Comment: Demon's Souls isn't actually that difficult - you just can't charge in like most hack'n'slash games. Be patient, learn your enemy's movements and weaknesses, then exploit them. Use rolling and blocking, and never leave yourself short of stamina.

Comment: @YellowMegaMan I agree 100% and thought the same thing I was playing. Most people are just used to games today where they hold your hand and you can mindlessly swing your sword around and win.

Comment: @YellowMegaMan +1 for mention of stamina

Answer (score 4):

No, the controller does not add artificial difficulty to Demon's Souls. Actually, the controls are very good, in my opinion.

The tutorial at the beginning of the game does a good job of teaching you the controls, so make sure you play through it.

Comment: Also a good answer...